# Double.TryParse thousand separator returns unexpected result

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

I just ran into something very strange, and was just wondering if I was missing something.

I was trying to parse a string (with thousand separators) into a double, and found the below issue.

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture; // en-ZA
string numberGroupSeparator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator; //numberGroupSeparator = ,
string numberDecimalSeparator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;//numberDecimalSeparator = .
string strValue = "242,445.24";
double try1;
double try2;
bool btry1 = Double.TryParse(strValue, out try1); //try1 = 242445.24 : btry1 = true
bool btry2 = Double.TryParse(strValue, NumberStyles.Any, null, out try2); //try2 = 0.0 : btry2 = false <- STRANGE
double try3 = Convert.ToDouble(strValue); //try3 = 242445.24
```

Now the reason why I didnt just want to use `Convert.ToDouble` is due to scientific notation which has given me some problems before.

Does anybody know why this might be?

**EDIT:**

I have update my current culture info.

Comment: why aren't you passing the `IFormatProvider`?

Comment: For the record, I am getting correct results in all three calls. What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: What does Double.TryParse return in this case? True or false? Cause if parsing fails result is set to 0

Comment: I am also getting a correct parse in all three cases after setting `Thread.Current.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-us")`.

Comment: @Rotem: From MSDN: "`Any` Indicates that all styles except `AllowHexSpecifier` are used. This is a composite number style."

Comment: Normally does NumberStyles.Any include AllowThousands

Comment: With en-ZA I get an exception for try3. Start you sample with `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-ZA");` so that we all talk about the same thing.

Comment: I think the problem might be that `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-ZA").NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator;` returns a white space.

Comment: @Henk These are the results I get, don't know about the OP.

Comment: Apparently the OP had a tweaked en-ZA. Root of the whole problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its working on my machine as expected, so I believe it has to do with the Current Culture. Try using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null` in your `TryParse`

```
Double.TryParse(strValue, NumberStyles.Any,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out try2);
```

It is failing for your current specified culture `en-ZA`, I tried the following code and `try2` is holding 0.0

```
 Double.TryParse(strValue, NumberStyles.Any,new CultureInfo("en-ZA"), out try2);
```

Comment: I will give this a go and see what happens. I see you say that it failed whe using Culture Info en-ZA, even though the numberGroupSeparator is ",". Do you possibly know why?

Comment: @astander, I am not sure, I am searching about it, if I find something  , will let you know

Answer (score 4):

### Updated (correct) answer, after much digging

You say that your current culture is `en-ZA`, but checking

```
new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-ZA").NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator
```

we see that the value is the empty string and not `","` as the question states. So if we set `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` to `new CultureInfo("en-ZA")` then parsing fails even for `try1`.

After manually setting it to `","` with

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
```

it transpires that parsing into `try1` is successful. Parsing into `try2` still fails.

For the `TryParse` overload used in `try2` the documentation is pretty clear that the current thread culture is used when the format provider is `null`, so something else must be going on...

After carefully comparing `InvariantCulture.NumberFormat` to that of the en-ZA culture, I noticed that the cultures also differ in their currency formats. Trying

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
```

hit the jackpot: parsing succeeds! So what's really going on is that **when using `NumberStyles.All`, the parse treats the number as currency**.

The hypothesis can be verified if you try

```
double.TryParse(strValue,
                NumberStyles.Any & ~NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol, null, out try2);
```

which succeeds without needing to mess with the currency separators (of course the `NumberGroupSeparator` does have to be appropriate)!

Comment: @astander: Turns out I was initially wrong, but I did finally hit upon the correct answer. Please take a look at the edit.

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic. Thank you for the explenation.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.80).aspx)  says that 0.0 is returned, when the conversation fails.

Most likely TryParse returns false, and you should try calling Parse, to get an exception message that might tell you what is wrong.

Comment: i think, its because of the formatProvider is NULL. I don't see that it is allowed to be nulled ( only in byte: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/tkktxbeh.aspx it is listed as nullable/defaulting)

Comment: @Najzero - "If provider is null or a NumberFormatInfo object cannot be obtained, the format information for the current culture is used."

Comment: The exceptions from Parse are equally (un)helpful.